# C# Error Inserting into SQL Server Identity Column Using SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server 2014 developer edition, and Visual Studio 2013 with C# to try and interact with a database. I'm using the SqlClient and SqlParameter classes to interface with the database.

I'm encountering an issue when trying to insert into a database table that has an identity column. Previously when using MySQL, I have just left the "id" column out of the statement and it is generated for me when the query runs, however SqlClient doesn't seem to like this approach.

When I execute my query I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'INVENTOR.dbo.inv_products'; column does >not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

When I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio and don't specify a value for ID, the query executes without a problem, and the ID is generated for me  by the identity column.

If I try and specify a random number as the ID in SSMS it throws an error that I can't insert an explicit value into an identity column. Similarly if I try and allow null values in the identity column an error is thrown.

The code I use to execute the query:

```
        // Add to products table.
        SqlCommand insertProductTable = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO inv_products(product_name,product_code,product_taxable) VALUES(@name,@sku,@taxable); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", this.sql);
        insertProductTable.Parameters.Add(productName);
        insertProductTable.Parameters.Add(productSKU);
        insertProductTable.Parameters.Add(productTaxable);

        int id = 0; // This is the ID of the product as stored in the table.

        this.sql.Open();
        id = (int) insertProductTable.ExecuteScalar();
        this.sql.Close();
```

Is there a way to get SqlClient to insert using an identity column correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS-SQL , an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column is not random number. As the name implies it a unique value which you can identify a specific row using it's value.

The correct way would be not to worry about the value of this columns, and let SQL-Server manage it for you.

If you still wish to manage it yourself, you can run [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) , and after that you will be able to insert any (unique) value to the ID column.

Please note that if this is a one time thing you are trying to do, don't forget to run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` once you are done.

**Edit 1:**
Following up on comments, Your C# implementation looks OK. My advice would be to use an SQL profiler in order to see what exactly you Server is receiving, and then try running it in SSMS.
I find it the easiest way to debug such issues.

**Edit 2:**
After Getting Profiler results, I ran the following script based on it:

```
BEGIN TRAN

create table inv_products (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    product_name varchar(256),
    product_code varchar(256),
    product_taxable int
);
GO

exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO inv_products(product_name,product_code,product_taxable) VALUES(@name,@sku,@taxable); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();',N'@name nvarchar(12),@sku nvarchar(14),@taxable bit',@name=N'Test Product',@sku=N'LONDTEST546124',@taxable=1

ROLLBACK
```

Everything seems to work perfectly...

Comment: Hi - I don't want to manage it myself, hence I left it out of the queries, but when I leave it out and let SQL Server manage it for me, SqlClient in C# returns an exception saying I can't enter a null value into that field.

Comment: @BnMcg In SSMS, Did you set the columns as identity + set the `seed` and `increment` values?

Comment: In SSMS the identity specification is set to "Yes", is identity is set to "Yes", Identity Increment is set to 1, and identity seed is set to 1.

Comment: @BnMcg Until you post your response, The best way to handle issues such as this one, is to use an **SQL profiler** in order to see what exactly your server is getting, and then run it VIA SSMS.

Comment: @BnMcg Following up on my previous comment, please try the profiler and post the results + the exact error message.

Comment: The SQL Server 2014 Profiler Trace returns:

`exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO inv_products(product_name,product_code,product_taxable) VALUES(@name,@sku,@taxable); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();',N'@name nvarchar(12),@sku nvarchar(14),@taxable bit',@name=N'Test Product',@sku=N'LONDTEST546124',@taxable=1`

Running that query in SSMS returns the same error as in Visual Studio.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51967/discussion-between-avi-turner-and-bnmcg)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce it but with no success. Below is the code that i have tried, and it run with not problems (note that i nedded to have a `Convert.ToInteger` to avoid an exception). Is it possible to see how your table is created?

**SQL**

```
create table myTable (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    name varchar(256),
    sku varchar(256),
    tax int
);
```

**C#**

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connStr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            connStr.InitialCatalog = "testDB";
            connStr.DataSource = "127.0.0.1";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr.ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable(name, sku, tax) values (@name, @sku, @tax); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "name value";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sku", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "sku value";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tax", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;

                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    Console.WriteLine("value: {0}", id);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cann't insert value for identity column value. but you can use IDENT_CURRENT( 'table_name' ) function for get current identity value , identity column is autoincrement value